# How to perform division operation on encrypted data with binary operations by using HElib or SEAL?

Tags: encryption, homomorphism

We’ve met some problems when we’re trying to  Implement fully homomorphic encryption through the algorithms which are supplied in HElib. We’re wondering whether we have to build some new homomorphic method, division or comparison for instance,  by using the binary operations or not?